# How to make a nested looping from three tables of database?

Tags: php

I have 3 tables : `m_house`,`m_progress` and `t_report`.

`m_house`

```
|id_house|number_house|
+--------+------------+
|1       |A23         |
+--------+------------+
|2       |A24         |
+--------+------------+
|3       |A25         |
+--------+------------+
and so on...
```

`m_progres`

```
|id_progress|name_progress|
+-----------+-------------+
|1          |floor        |
+-----------+-------------+
|2          |wall         |
+-----------+-------------+
|3          |roof         |
+-----------+-------------+
and so on...
```

`t_report`

```
|id_report|id_house|id_progress|date      |
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
|1        |1       |1          |2021-01-02|
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
|2        |1       |2          |2021-01-05|
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
|3        |2       |1          |2021-01-09|
+---------+--------+-----------+----------+
and so on...
```

What I want to make is table like this :

```
|number_house|floor|wall|roof|
+------------+-----+----+----+
|A23         |1    |1   |    |
+------------+-----+----+----+
|A24         |1    |    |    |
+------------+-----+----+----+
```

1 mean true. So far I thinking using nesting looping method. So in first loop is to loop `number_house` witch is `<tr>` and second loop in first loop is to loop the `t_report` data. But the problem I don't know how array data it's must be. Maybe you have another method.

Comment: If these are SQL Tables, then why not fetching data in the format you need instead of crunching data in code?

Comment: like I say, I open for any method. But I can't figure it out how to make query like format I want. I just thinking to do that in PHP looping using for

Comment: "SELECT * FROM t_report LEFT JOIN m_progress ON m_progress.id_progress = t_report.m_progress LEFT JOIN m_house ON m_house.id_house = t_report.id_house" -> this is probably what you want

Answer (score 1):

This query statement will fetch the result in the way you want

```
SELECT results.house_number, SUM(results.Floors) > 0 as Floors, SUM(results.Walls) > 0 as Walls, SUM(results.Roofs) > 0 as Roofs FROM (

SELECT house_number, COUNT(floors.name_progress) AS Floors, COUNT(walls.name_progress) AS Walls, COUNT(roofs.name_progress) AS Roofs FROM t_report

LEFT JOIN m_house ON m_house.id_house = t_report.id_house
LEFT JOIN m_progress floors ON floors.id_progress = t_report.id_progress AND floors.name_progress = "floor"
LEFT JOIN m_progress walls ON walls.id_progress = t_report.id_progress AND walls.name_progress = "wall"
LEFT JOIN m_progress roofs ON roofs.id_progress = t_report.id_progress AND roofs.name_progress = "roof"

GROUP BY t_report.id_house, house_number, floors.name_progress, walls.name_progress, roofs.name_progress) results

GROUP BY house_number
```

If you start doing queries like this then it is best to look at how you can best reorganize your table data. The > 0 part on first line that appears 3 times, if you remove them, you'll get total number of floors, walls and roofs instead of 1 being true.